# Connect by prior with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have some data in BigQuery table that looks like this:

```
Email, Manager_Email
a@abc.com, b@abc.com
b@abc.com, z@abc.com
c@abc.com, b@abc.com
d@abc.com, e@abc.com
e@abc.com, ceo@abc.com
z@abc.com, ceo@abc.com
```

I would like to get the following:

```
Email, Manager_Email, Last_Manager
a@abc.com, b@abc.com, z@abc.com
b@abc.com, z@abc.com, z@abc.com
c@abc.com, b@abc.com, z@abc.com
d@abc.com, e@abc.com, e@abc.com
e@abc.com, ceo@abc.com, ceo@abc.com
z@abc.com, ceo@abc.com, ceo@abc.com
```

In this table, the column Last_Manager means the "last manager before the CEO". If the direct manager is the CEO then it's CEO.

Problem is, the hierachy of the first employee and the last manager can be espaced with at least 5 employees.

Do you know if it's possible with BigQuery ?
At least if possible, a solution with ignoring "If the direct manager is the CEO then it's CEO" is ok to me.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following query:

```
select a.email, a.manager_email, 
(case when a.manager_email like '%ceo%' then a.manager_email
when b.manager_email like '%ceo%' then a.manager_email 
else b.manager_email end
) last_manager 

from test a
left join test b
on a.manager_email = b.email
```

Here I am using self join. 
Please update the column names according to your schema.

Comment: With this request, I get the manager of my manager. I would like to get the manager before the CEO in all cases. For example for the following: A -> B -> C -> D -> CEO. I get C but I would like to get D.